# como insertar las coordenadas en una mapa en R

Tags: r

Alguien podría ayudarme a decirme como puedo incluir cada una de las coordenadas al lado de los puntos correspondientes del mapa?
Muchas gracias y saludos

```
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
ree <- "7903714VK0870S"
reerest<-"0001QM"
RC <- paste(ree, reerest, sep = "")
RC
rc123 <- catr_wfs_get_parcels_parcel(RC)
rc456<-ggplot(rc123) + geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(fill = "aquamarine", color = "black")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 1, hjust = 1, size = 9))
rc456
p2parc<-rc456 +
  annotate("point", x = coordenadasparc$longitud, y = coordenadasparc$latitud, colour = "orange", cex = 3)+
  annotate("point", x = coordenadasparc$longitud[1], y = coordenadasparc$latitud[1], colour = "blue", cex = 4)+
  annotate("point", x = coordenadasparc$longitud[2], y = coordenadasparc$latitud[2], colour = "grey", cex = 4)
p2parc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require( ggrepel )
require( purrr )      #  %>%, map_chr

puntos <- data.frame(
    lons = coordenadasparc$longitud
  , lats = coordenadasparc$latitud
)

puntos$nombres <- seq( nrow( puntos )) %>%
  map_chr(
    ~sprintf(
      "%f,%f", puntos[ .x, 'lons' ], puntos[ .x, 'lats ' ] 
    )
  )

p2parc +
  geom_point(
      data = puntos
    , aes( x = lons, y = lats )
    , size = 3
  ) +
    geom_label_repel(
        data = puntos
      , aes( x = lons, y = lats, label = nombres )
      , size = 3
      , color = 'red'
      , point.padding = 0.8
      , box.padding = 0.8
    )

# Se puede usar geom_text_repel en vez de geom_label_repel
#  geom_label_repel  -----> con cajas
#  geom_text_repel   -----> sin cajas
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. pero la linea:   map_chr( ~sprintf( "%f,%f", Points[ .x, 'lon' ], Points[ .x, 'lat' ] )), no me funciona, me da error

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).